# Cron Schedule Mondays 6AM

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

How can I schedule this batch class to run on every Monday at 6AM?

```
public class BatchCount implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([/*query*/]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, REOHQ__REOHQ_Company__c[] records) {
        /*logic*/
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    }
}
```

Comment: did you look at `CronTrigger` in the doc along with schedulable apex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the Schedulable interface, then you can schedule the class in the Setup screen or by writing some execute anonymous code:

```
public class BatchCount implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Schedulable {
    public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        // ...
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, REOHQ__REOHQ_Company__c[] records) {
        // ...
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can schedule it like this:

```
System.schedule('WeeklyBatch', '0 0 6 ? * MON', new BatchCount());
```

Comment: Do i need to write system.schedule in setup screen every time?

Comment: @Salesfor_dev No, the first time you schedule it, it will be scheduled for 6 am (0 0 6) to run every Monday (? * MON).

Comment: Its getting me an error like Invalid type :ScheduableContext at line 2 column 25

Comment: @Salesfor_dev Was a typo. I meant `SchedulableContext`.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange, but only one possible way to schedule job in my case was setup the last (optional) argument. So to run job I have used: '0 0 6 ? * MON *' instead of:'0 0 6 ? * MON'.
First when I tried to use '0 0 6 ? * MON' I constantly got error: System.StringException: Unexpected end of expression. The same issue was in tests.

It is more strange, that after I deleted the job and recreate it using '0 0 6 ? * MON', it worked fine!